# Tkinter canvas acting different for the same image

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code that display two images from a file inside two canvases. For some reason, the first image doesn't fill up the whole canvas and there's about 3 pixels space on right side and at the bottom. But the second image filled up its canvas quite nicely. I used very similar code to display both image. This is code -

```
    self.frame1=Frame(self.root,width=self.width,height=self.height)
    self.frame1.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=10,padx=20)
    self.canvas1=Canvas(self.frame1,bg='LIGHT GREY',width=self.width,height=self.height)        
    self.canvas1.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH,padx=0,pady=0)
    self.tkpi = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.imageorg)
    self.label_imageorg = self.canvas1.create_image(0,0,image=self.tkpi,anchor=NW)

    self.frame=Frame(self.root,width=self.width,height=self.height)
    self.frame.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=10)
    self.canvas2=Canvas(self.frame,bg='#FFFFFF',width=self.width,height=self.height,\
        scrollregion=(0,0,self.width,self.height))
    self.vbar=Scrollbar(self.frame,orient=VERTICAL)
    self.vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
    self.vbar.config(command=self.canvas2.yview)
    self.canvas2.config(yscrollcommand=self.vbar.set)
    self.canvas2.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
    self.tkpi2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.history[0])
    self.label_imagemod = self.canvas2.create_image(0,0,image=self.tkpi2,anchor=NW)
```

Why could be the cause of it?Does anyone know? 
P.S : self.history[0] is just a copy of self.imageorg. (Copied with PIL copy method)

Comment: My guess is that they aren't actually copies of each other. Maybe you should try comparing the images? Maybe you overlooked an argument, and the copy was scaled or cropped for some reason.

Comment: I tried using the same image(self.imageorg) for the both canvases, but the problem still exist - first one doesn't fill up but the second one does. But I found the culprit though. It's not the image, it's the canvas. For some reason, the first canvas, doesn't display image at 0,0 coordinate, but x at < 0 and y at <0. When I change coordinates to create_image(2,3,..). The problem solved. But why is that happened?

Comment: The code for the two canvases is not *exactly* the same.  I would reduce the differences one at a time until the display difference disappears.